# Tooltip is not working in bootstrap modal?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-slider

I used seiyria angular-bootstrap-slider for range slider,but initially when page loads the tooltip is at wrong position.when it is placed in normal page it is working fine,but in modal it is intially at wrong position,but when I click it will be set.So how to slove this issue.

HTMl:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" value="modal"
        onclick="confirmChangeMaxHours();"><i
            class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i> Adjust Value
```

Here is the link:

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YwJNZP)

I found this suggestion in some site:

```
 setTimeout(function() {
slider.slider("relayout");
}, 500);
```

But,where I have to give setTimeout function,I tried to give but it is showing error like Slider is not defined.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: will you please elaborate your issue, where you want a tool-tip on button hover or in modal? what do you mean by page load? what is not rendering in bootstrap modal?

Comment: @this.girish intially when I open modal,the tooltip is at wrong position,as shown in the link ie; it is at some distance from the slider handler

Comment: @this.girish I updated the question once please check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this css into your code

```
.tooltip{

  margin-left:-32px!important
}
```

Comment: no,I have to set some default value,Iam asking the slider handle is at correct position only,but tooltip must be on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

In my implementation the modal was over the tooltip. So, to fix it, I put the tooltip over all elements by adding a big z-index to all tooltips.

```
.tooltip.tooltip-top,
.tooltip.tooltip-bottom,
.tooltip.tooltip-left,
.tooltip.tooltip-right {
  z-index: 100000;
}
```